# database error when widget updates

Tags: android, database, widget, nullpointerexception

I have a DB in my app which normally works perfectly.
Now, I have added a widget with an update function which also accesses the DB.
Once in a while, I get this error but only from within the widget update method.

```
Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
```

Is there some kind of restriction on accessing a DB from within widget update method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do any disk IO from the widget's BroadCast receiver (`onUpdate()`). Start a service that fetches the data and does the actual update. You might want to use an `IntentServcie` since it starts a worker thread by default.

Comment: thanks for that - I totally forgot about this - hopefully there will not be any more DB errors then